# RStudio, difference between Run and Source on the result of a script

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a problem on a part of a script that rename an object, here an example:

```
rm( list = ls(  ) )
# create object 'mes' in 'A.rdata'
setwd( "k:/My R space/" )
mes <- list(  a = c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c("a","b","c","d") )
save( mes, file = "A.rdata" )
rm( list = ls(  ) )
cat( "\14" )
# rename object 'mes' to 'essai'
setwd( "k:/My R space/" )
file = "A.rdata"
env=parent.frame()
#
tmp<-new.env()
load.names <- load( file, tmp )
Map( assign, "essai", mget( load.names, envir = tmp ), MoreArgs = list(envir = env ) )
ls.str( essai ) }
```

When I run this with 'Source' it fails

```
> $essai
$essai$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$essai$b
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

> ls.str( essai )
Error in ls.str(essai) : object 'essai' not found
```

When I use Run, it works !

```
$essai
$essai$a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$essai$b
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

> ls.str( essai )
a : num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
b : chr [1:4] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: `MoreArgs =` is `mapply()` syntax, not `Map()` syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`essai` is assigned in `env`.

But `env` is defined as `parent.frame()`.

When you use Run, `parent.frame()` gives `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`.

From `source`, with the default `local = FALSE`, your script is also executed in "The global environment `.GlobalEnv`, more often known as the user's workspace" (quoting from `help(".GlobalEnv")`), which you can check if you add `environment()` to your script.

But (again!). Even though the expressions are executed in `.GlobalEnv`, they are evaluated with calls to other (probably deeply nested) other functions from the R code of `source()`. And that is what you get with `parent.frame()`, the calling environment of the evaluation function, which is itself an execution environment created on the fly inside the call to `source()`.

You can check it if you print `parent.frame()` in your script, you'll get a different value each time, for instance `<environment: 0x40dca18>`, then `<environment: 0x53be0f8>`, then...

Well, enough confusion.

When you do `ls.str( essai )` with Run, `essai` is easily found in `.GlobalEnv`, which is equal to `env`!

When you use `source()`, `essai` cannot be found in `.GlobalEnv` or any enclosing environment, since it belongs to `<environment: 0x53be0f8>` or whatever.

You can fix it with `ls.str(get("essai", envir = env))`